# What is meant by the distribution of an image dataset?

Tags: distributions, deep-learning, dataset, random-variable

In the context of image-based deep learning methods, a reference is often made to the distribution of a dataset without explicitly defining the random variable. I'd like to check if my interpretation of the distribution of an image dataset is correct.

Assuming a dataset of grayscale images with width `w` and height `h`, I think it makes most sense if the images in the dataset form a subset of the sample space of all the possible images, each image is a sample outcome and a multivariate random variable is defined such that it assigns a `w*h` dimensional vector to each image where elements correspond to pixel values in the image. Is this correct?

Comment: Yah, pretty much : )

Comment: Thanks! Could you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @AgostBiro you can always post an answer if the answer given deemed appropriate.